# Difference between SGA_target and Total System Global Area

Tags: oracle12c, in-memory-database

I am working on Oracle 12c in-memory database, for that I increase the MEMORY_TARGET to 32GB which is the size of my shared file system. When I restart the Oracle database is shows the Total System Global Area= 3.3286E+10 bytes, but after that when I use the command `ALTER SYSTEM SET SGA_TARGET = 28G SCOPE= SPFILE;` the system gives the error that `Specified value of MEMORY_TARGET is too small, needs to be at least 35136M`.

Is there a difference between SGA_target and Total System Global Area? and what is it?

Comment: The error message and command don't match. It looks like you really tried to set MEMORY_TARGET to less than the total or SGA_TARGET and PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET. [This might help](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/memory.htm#GUID-0E201F66-D280-472A-AD80-20AB8F7E9C01).

Comment: The value of sga_target controls the Total System Global Area. Check [this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SGA)

Answer (score 0):

SGA_Target is the size of the SGA  **not including** the PGA. Memory_Target includes both. If the PGA_target  + SGA_Target are > Memory_Target, you can get this error. Take a look at [this](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/622.automatic-memory-management-amm1) and [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1137385000346840516).

Comment: You are correct at 'SGA_Target is the size of the SGA not including the PGA' but INCORRECT at 'PGA_target + SGA_Target are > Memory_Target'. In fact, you are using sga_target > 0, you should have memory_target = 0 and vice versa to indicate that you intend to use ASMM or AMM. None of the referred links endorsed it either.

Comment: Actually the first link does support my answer. I should have written pga_aggregate_target. There is no "PGA_Target."   "If memory_target < (sga_target + pga_aggregate_target) the instance will fail to start returning an ORA-00838 error."

Comment: I think If you referred to this text from first link …
“The memory_target parameter combines the pre-Oracle 11g sga_target parameter value with the pga_aggregate_target parameter. … “

This is to give DBA an idea how to pre-compute ‘memory_target’ if you intend to switch from ASSM to AMM.

Comment: You will see same here too https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/memory003.htm
memory_target = sga_target + max(pga_aggregate_target, maximum PGA allocated)
However,  it does not mean that memory_target should always be > 0 even if I intend to use ASSM (sga_target, sga_max_size, pga_aggregate_target). I gave got all of my servers set to sga_xxx parameters > 0 but memory_target is still set to 0. But, I don’t see ORA-00838 on DB start-up.

Comment: When using AMM, the SGA_TARGET and PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET act as minimum size settings for their respective memory areas. However, To allow Oracle to take full control of the memory management, these parameters should be set to zero.

Comment: Yes, IF memory_target is set to 0. If it's not, then you get the error. That is the original, correct answer to the posters question. You didn't really answer the posters question - you told him how to solve it. Which is useful too. I tried to answer the question. I agree that if one sets SGA or PGA targets that memory_target should be set to 0, as it is on your systems and mine as well. The issue is the poster has it set to 32GB AND is setting SGA and I think the SGA Plus the PGA is > memory_target and hence the error.

Comment: I get your point. I don't think one get to see ORA-00838 other than on a db start-up. I think, poster either published incorrect information or in the incorrect order. @kadsank - Are you able to startup db? can you share output of 'show parameters target' and 'show parameters memory'?

Comment: You are correct - the ORA-00838 will be seen at startup. The OP is getting the error because he's changing the setting while server is up - trying to write invalid init params to the SPFILE and the server won't let him do it because his memory_target is not 0 - per your earlier point and SGA + PGA > memory_target. As you said above, he should set memory_target to 0 then he would be able to do what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change sga_target if you intend to use memory_target. You should choose between AMM (memory_target) or ASMM (sga_target, pga_aggregate_target) memory management for your DB instance and configure DB parameters accordingly.

> Is there a difference between SGA_target and Total System Global Area?
>   and what is it?

FYI - System Global Area  is SGA and comprises multiple memory sub-components. sga_target allows oracle to dynamically allocate memory to the System Global Area (SGA)

--**EDIT**

When using AMM, the SGA_TARGET and PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET act as minimum size settings for their respective memory areas. However, To allow Oracle to take full control of the memory management, these parameters should be set to zero

Comment: Also, in the Shared Server connection mode the PGA moves into the SGA, so that must be accounted for.